# MySQL++ Invalid Arguments Error

Tags: c++, mysql++

SSQLS defines in `MySQLHelper.h`

```
#ifndef SRC_INCLUDE_UTIL_MYSQLHELPER_H_
#define SRC_INCLUDE_UTIL_MYSQLHELPER_H_

#if!defined(EXPAND_MY_SSQLS_STATICS)
#define MYSQLPP_SSQLS_NO_STATICS
#endif
#include <ssqls.h>
sql_create_7(FaceTable, 1, 7, mysqlpp::sql_int, id, mysqlpp::sql_int, label,
            mysqlpp::sql_int, gender, mysqlpp::sql_double, genderconfidence,
            mysqlpp::sql_int, age, mysqlpp::sql_double, ageconfidence,
            mysqlpp::sql_datetime, date)

using namespace std;
mysqlpp::Connection connect();
```

Then is `MySQLHelper.cpp`

```
#define EXPAND_MY_SSQLS_STATICS
#include "include/Util/MySQLHelper.h"

mysqlpp::Connection connect() {
    const char *SERVER = "127.0.0.1";
    const char * USER = "root";
    const char * PASSWORD = "123456";
    const char *DB  ="FaceDB";
    mysqlpp::Connection conn(false);
    if (conn.connect(DB, SERVER, USER, PASSWORD)) {
        return conn;
    }
}
```

I want to use SSQLS in `FaceDAO.h`

```
#ifndef SRC_INCLUDE_DAO_FACEDAO_H_
#define SRC_INCLUDE_DAO_FACEDAO_H_

#include "include/Core/Face.h"
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include "include/DAO/FaceEntity.h"
using namespace std;
class FaceDAO {
private:
    mysqlpp::Connection conn;
public:
    FaceDAO();
    void insert(Face face, time_t time);
};

#endif /* SRC_INCLUDE_DAO_FACEDAO_H_ */
```

Then is `FaceDAO.cpp`

```
#include "include/Util/MySQLHelper.h"
#include "include/DAO/FaceDAO.h"
FaceDAO::FaceDAO() {
    this->conn = connect();
}
void FaceDAO::insert(Face face, time_t datetime) {
    mysqlpp::sql_int id(0);
    mysqlpp::sql_int label(face.getLabel());
    mysqlpp::sql_int gender(face.getGender() == "male" ? 1 : 0);
    mysqlpp::sql_double genderconfidence(face.getGenderConfidence());
    mysqlpp::sql_int age(face.getAge());
    mysqlpp::sql_double ageconfidence(face.getAgeConfidence());
    mysqlpp::sql_datetime date(datetime);
    FaceTable entity(id, label, gender, genderconfidence, age, ageconfidence,
            date);
    mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query();
    try {
        query.insert(entity);
        query.execute();
    } catch (const mysqlpp::Exception &er) {
        cerr << "Error: " << er.what() << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

but compiler told me `query.insert(entity);` is error
The error is below

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: mysqlpp::Query & insert(const #0 &) mysqlpp::Query & insert(#0, #0) '
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, It seems eclipse error.
Try right-clicking on your project and selecting Index->Rebuild from the 
menu.